# Discretizing regions with pointy boundaries

Tags: computational-geometry, finite-element-method, mesh

I'm trying to discretize a region with "pointy" boundaries to study dielectric breaking on electrodes with pointy surfaces. So far I've tried 3 types of boundaries, but the meshing functions stall indefinitely. I've let it run for several hours and it doesn't complete. Seems strange that it would take so long

```
ParametricPlot[{-Cos[u] (1.2 - Cos[(u - Pi)/2]^6) (0.2 + 
     Cos[10 u]^10), 
  Sin[u] (1.2 - Cos[(u - Pi)/2]^6) (0.2 + Cos[10 u]^10)}, {u, 0, 
  2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
ir = ParametricRegion[{{r Cos[u], r Sin[u]}, 
   0 <= u <= 2 Pi && 
    0 <= r <= (0.5 + 
       Cos[(u - (Pi/2))/2]^8 Cos[14 (u - (Pi/2))]^8)}, {r, u}]
ird = DiscretizeRegion[ir, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.02] (* never completes *)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
m = ToElementMesh[ir, 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", "SamplePoints" -> 50}, 
  "MeshOrder" -> 1] (* never completes *)
```

Another attempt:

```
ParametricPlot[{ 
  Cos[u] Max[
    0.1, -Cos[u]] (1.2 - 
     Abs[Sin[10 Abs[((u - Pi))^(1/2)]]^(1/3)]), (1.2 - 
     Abs[Sin[10 Abs[((u - Pi))^(1/2)]]^(1/3)]) Sin[u] Max[
    0.1, -Cos[u]]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
ir2 = ParametricRegion[{{r Cos[u], r Sin[u]}, 
   0 <= u <= 2 Pi && 
    0 <= r <= 
     Max[0.1, -Cos[u]] (1.2 - 
        Abs[Sin[10 Abs[((u - Pi))^(1/2)]]^(1/3)])}, {r, u}]
m = ToElementMesh[ir2, 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", "SamplePoints" -> 50}, 
  "MeshOrder" -> 1] (* never completes *)
```

Last attempt:

```
ParametricPlot[{-Cos[u] (1.2 - Cos[(u - Pi)/2]^6) (0.2 + 
     Cos[10 u]^10), 
  Sin[u] (1.2 - Cos[(u - Pi)/2]^6) (0.2 + Cos[10 u]^10)}, {u, 0, 
  2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
ir3 = ParametricRegion[{{r Cos[u], r Sin[u]}, 
   0 <= u <= 2 Pi && 
    0 <= r <= (1.2 - Cos[(u - Pi)/2]^6) (0.2 + Cos[10 u]^10)}, {r, u}]
m = ToElementMesh[ir3, 
  "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"RegionPlot", "SamplePoints" -> 50}, 
  "MeshOrder" -> 1] (* never completes *)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest not going through the `Plot` functions for this. They're designed to produce a good *visual* representation of the region, which is not necessarily the same as a good representation for doing numerical computation on. Besides, the plot already discretizes the region into a polygon, so the mesh refinement options of `DiscretizeRegion` or `ToElementMesh` cannot help to improve the accuracy of the boundary. It's best to maintain an analytical representation of the region right up until it goes into the mesh generation routine.

Unfortunately, Mathematica is not very good at dealing with `ParametricRegion`s. (It can't even do

```
RegionPlot[
 ParametricRegion[{r Cos@t, r Sin@t}, {{r, 1, 2}, {t, 0, Pi/2}}], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}]
```

correctly.) Your region can be easily expressed as an `ImplicitRegion` instead:

```
region = ImplicitRegion[
   With[{r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], u = ArcTan[-x, y]}, r <= f[u]], {x, y}];
RegionPlot[region, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 0.6}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

(Mathematica also has a hard time figuring out the bounds of the region automatically, so sometimes you have to specify them manually.) Then `DiscretizeRegion` works fine:

```
DiscretizeRegion[region, {{-1.5, 0.6}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
 MaxCellMeasure -> 0.02, AccuracyGoal -> 3]
```

[image]

as does `ToElementMesh`:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[region, {{-1.5, 0.6}, {-1.5, 1.5}}, 
   "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "Continuation"];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer. I just added code that in case the `ParametricRegion` can not be converted to an `ImplikcitRegion` a message will be generated indicating that this conversion failed. Using an `ImplicitRegion` is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

```
fn = {-Cos[u] (1.2 - Cos[(u - Pi)/2]^6) (0.2 + Cos[10 u]^10), 
   Sin[u] (1.2 - Cos[(u - Pi)/2]^6) (0.2 + Cos[10 u]^10)};
plot =
  ParametricPlot[fn, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotPoints -> Round[2 Pi (Sqrt@MaxValue[#.# &@D[fn, u],
          u])/0.2], PlotRange -> All];

Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> Polygon[p], Infinity] // 
  First // DiscretizeRegion
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[Show[plot /. Line -> Polygon, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I get an error if I don't reset `PlotRange`.  Perhaps a bug.